# what is the functionality of dt.jar file in Java?

Tags: java, java-8

I want to know the functionality of dt.jar file in java which is located in jdk/lib folder. I have read oracle official documentation but can't understand their talk given below

"dt.jar, the **DesignTime** archive of **BeanInfo** files that tell interactive development environments (IDEs) how to display the Java components and how to let the developer customize them for an application."

Can anybody explain this to me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks. @Aaron . I have edited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `dt.jar` library is used by IDE applications to help design Swing GUI.

Hence, it is useful at *design time* , and is not to be included at *runtime*.

The jar contains [BeanInfo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/BeanInfo.html) classes for the Swing components, along with images representing the components.

From the **Java Examples in a Nutshell, 3rd Edition** book (Chapter 15.4 : Custom Events), by *David Flanagan* :

> This BeanInfo class specifies a number of pieces of information for
>   our bean:
>
> - An icon that represents the bean.
> - A BeanDescriptor object, which includes a reference to a Customizer    class for the bean. We'll see an implementation of this class later
>     in the chapter.
> - A list of the supported properties of the bean, along with a short    description of each one. Some beanbox tools (but not Sun's beanbox)
>     display these strings to the user in some useful way.
> - A method that returns the most commonly customized property of the    bean; this is called the "default" property.
> - A reference to a PropertyEditor class for one of the properties.

This helps IDEs to provide useful graphical design tools using those bean components :

[image]

You may find more information here : [Bean Customization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/advanced/customization.html)